# Vue router dynamic link and children reload page - not load correctly component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I add to my `routes` file `path` with `children`:

```
path: '/warehouse/:id',
name: 'ShowWarehouse',
component: ShowWarehouse,
children: [{
        path: 'edit',
        name: 'EditWarehouse',
        component: EditWarehouse
    }
]
```

Now in component `ShowWarehouse` I have:

```
        <div v-if="!changeEdit">
            <div v-if="warehouseData">
                <div>Name: {{ warehouseData.warehouse.name }}</div>
                <div>
                    <router-link
                    :to="{ name: 'EditWarehouse', params: {id: warehouseData.warehouse.id }}"
                     >Edit</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <router-view v-else></router-view>
```

When the user click `edit` button I need load component `EditWarehouse`, but component `ShowWarehouse` must be disappear, and if user back (without `/edit`) disappear componet `EditWarehouse` and load component `ShowWarehouse`. I write method in `watch`:

```
watch: {
    $route() {
        if (this.$route.path == '/warehouse/' + id_get_from_API + '/edit') {
            this.changeEdit = true;
        } else {
            this.changeEdit = false;
        }            
    }
},
```

The problem is when the user is at `mydomain.com/warehouse/23/edit` and click reload page (F5), then Vue loads component `ShowWarehouse` instead of loading `EditWarehouse`.

I using `mode: 'history'`.

Comment: What are you using server side? When using history mode, there [is some additional configuration you have to set up](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations). Just as a test, to make sure the issue has to do with history mode, could you disable it and try again? Can you reproduce the issue without history mode?

Comment: @MattOestreich When I remove `mode: 'history'` problem is this same, I using `artisan serve`, I added `.htaccess` with Apache configuration, but not help

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

From the Vue.JS website: "Vue does provide a more generic way to observe and react to data changes **on a Vue instance**: watch properties." When you refresh the page the watch() method will not be executed because it is a new Vue instance and no data has changed on the Vue instance yet. You should probably use a different pattern to determine which component to show. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property)

## Solution:

I suggest making the EditWarehouse a sibling route to ShowWarehouse, <s>and make EditWarehouse its own component</s> *(you already have this)*. Your router-link in the ShowWarehouse component can stay the same.

Code Snippet:

```js
const ShowWarehouse = {
  template: `<div><h1>ShowWarehouse</h1> <div v-if="warehouseData">
    <div>Name: {{ warehouseData.warehouse.name }}</div>
    <div>ID: {{ $route.params.id }}</div>
    <div>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'EditWarehouse'}">Edit</router-link>
    </div>
  </div></div>`,
  computed: {
    warehouseData: function() {
      let data;

      let id = this.$route.params.id;
      if (id) {
        data = {
          warehouse: {
            name: 'Some Warehouse Name',
            id: id
          }
        }
      }

      return data;
    }
  }
};

const EditWarehouse = {
  template: "<h1>EditWarehouse [{{ $route.params.id }}]</h1>"
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: '/warehouse/:id',
      name: 'ShowWarehouse',
      component: ShowWarehouse
    },
    {
      path: '/warehouse/:id/edit',
      name: 'EditWarehouse',
      component: EditWarehouse
    }
  ]
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'ShowWarehouse', params: { id: 123 }}">Go to Warehouse 123</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view/>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the same code:
https://jsfiddle.net/austinwasinger/oruswb3a/39/